# Is it grammatically correct to use "if" and "or not" in the same sentence?

Tags: conditionals

My student's workbook states that the following sentence is grammatically incorrect because "if" and "or not" can not be used in the same sentence:

**“Let's find out if there was fire or not.”**

I can not find a grammar rule that confirms the workbook's explanation that "if" and "or not" can not be used in the same sentence.

I've also found other examples where "if" and "or not" is used in the same sentence:

"We'll find out if there's a Salinger archive or not," Mr. Enniss said.

"We don't know if it matters or not".

“It does not really matter if you agree or not"

What I did find out was that *"whether" and "or not"* should be avoided in the same sentence (in written Eng.) because essentially "whether" already give the option for something to "happen or not".

Can anyone please help me with the question: Can "if...or not" be used in the same sentence like in the example **“Let's find out if there was fire or not.”**

Thank you.

Comment: I've never heard of such a rule, though I agree that _or not_ is superfluous after _whether_.

Comment: A matter of style, emphasis. English need not be stripped to the minimal logic requirements.

Comment: The rule is that "if" is not permitted when "or not" immediately follows the subordinator, e.g. *"I don't know if or not she'll accept". But it's fine when "or not" follows the first coordinate, as in "I don't know whether/if she'll accept or not".

Comment: When *if* introduces subordinate interrogatives (i.e. questions), it is used in the same way as *whether*, and it is fine to use *or not*. When *if* is used to introduce a conditional clause, we cannot use *or not*.  **If you you pay me ten dollars or not, I won't help you* <--Conditional *if*, so *nor not* is not possible here. IT is fine in your example sentences.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite normal to add "or not" with "if", especially to establish true/false nature of a single fact( Here, the occurrence/ non-occurrence of fire).

Again,  since it appears that a *particular incidence* of fire is being referred to, the countable form, "a fire" is appropriate: 'Let's find out if there was a fire or not.'

In talking about fire incidents, we say, for example, *What needs to be done if there's a fire?*

Comment: Could you add support for your assertion (a suitable example sentence from a dictionary, linked and attributed?) And “I'm not sure if she's coming or not" sounds a lot better than "I'll stay in the town if the house survived the fire or not" ('whether' is fine in both, of course).

Comment: Fire incidents? How do these differ from fires?

Comment: Not quite. "Or not" is not permitted when it immediately follows the subordinator, e.g. "I don't know [whether / *if or not she'll accept]". And it's not permitted in exhaustive conditionals, e.g. "I'm going to play golf tomorrow [whether / *if you like it or not]".

Answer (score -1):

I find it bizarre that English is being taught in terms of learning arbitrary rules of this type. Even if the book is correct, understanding the logic will generally be easier and more useful for the learner. I suppose this question should really be on English Language Learners, but as there is an answer that regards the sentences as acceptable (and one can probably find many examples of its common use) I shall provide a suggestion of what might be behind this “rule”.

> It is possible that the criticism is because of the use of “if” rather
> than “whether” in sentences of this type involving alternatives.

To analyse the sentence I would recast it as:

“Let’s find out *whether or not* there was a fire.” Clearly, one cannot say “*if or not*”.

The counter-argument would be that the sentence is a contraction of:

“*Let’s find out if there was a fire, or* if there was *not* a fire.”

Then it would boil down to whether it is better to say “Let’s find out *whether*”. The [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=find+out+if%2C+find+out+whether&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfind%20out%20if%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfind%20out%20whether%3B%2Cc0) for the comparison shows “find out whether” being about more common than “find out if” until 1980.

However, despite my own personal preference for *whether*, the [Cambridge Dictionary’s entry on this topic](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/if-or-whether) maintains that both are currently acceptable, even with not, and only states that “if” is more common and “whether” more formal.

> So my answer? The book is probably wrong as regards the contemporary
> language, but may reflect the stricter approach to English of
> fifty years ago favoured by pedants such as I.